# Makefile error:No rule to m ake target

Tags: c, makefile

I am new to writing makefiles and have gone through several other questions on the same topic on stackoverflow but not able to work my code.

I am writing makefile to compile a single .C file in starting.

```
 CORE_DIR = ../..
 CODE_DIR = $(CORE_DIR)/code

 CC=gcc

 all: example.o

 example.o: $(CODE_DIR)/example.c $(CODE_DIR)/variable.h
      $(CC) $(CODE_DIR)/example.c -o output
```

I am executing command : make -f start.mk and getting error: No rule to make target for 'start.mk'.

Where am I getting wrong in this?

**EDIT:** using make -d start.mk(debug option) and changing all:output as said in comments..this is the following i am getting with more text which I was not able to copy. 
Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.c'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.cc'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.C'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.cpp'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.p'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.f'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.F'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.r'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.s'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.S'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Rejecting impossible implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.mod'.
 Trying pattern rule with stem `linux.mk'.
 Trying implicit prerequisite`linux.mk.sh'.
 Looking for a rule with intermediate file `linux.mk.sh'.
  Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
  Trying pattern rule with stem`linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `linux.mk.sh,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem`linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/linux.mk.sh,v'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem`linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `RCS/linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem`linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `s.linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying pattern rule with stem`linux.mk.sh'.
  Trying implicit prerequisite `SCCS/s.linux.mk.sh'.
 No implicit rule found for`linux.mk'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `linux.mk'.
No need to remake target`linux.mk'.
make: Nothing to be done for `linux.mk'.

Comment: Is the code in your question from the file 'start.mk'?

Comment: Yes, the makefile name is start.mk

Comment: Is the line beginning with `$(CC) ` indented with a tab (and not with spaces)?

Comment: yes, that line is intended with TAB

Comment: Not sure if this fixes your problem, but I would change the `all:` rule to: `all: output` and the `example.o:` rule to `output: $(CODE_DIR)/example.c $(CODE_DIR)/variable.h`.

Comment: If you use `-d` you still need to supply `-f` to specify that `start.mk` is a makefile and not a target, so try `make -d -f start.mk`.

Comment: The reason the answers are not helping you is that you are not being careful about your questions.  Why does the generated output list `linux.mk` if your makefile is called `start.mk`?  Obviously what you're typing at your prompt and what you're showing us here are not the same.  Second, the command `make -d start.mk` is wrong: you MUST have the `-f` flag if you want to name your makefile a non-standard name; it should be `make -d -f start.mk`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
CORE_DIR = ../..
CODE_DIR = $(CORE_DIR)/code

CC=gcc

all: example.o
    $(CC) -o output $<

example.o: $(CODE_DIR)/example.c $(CODE_DIR)/variable.h
    $(CC) -c $<
```

How to use this:

1. Put these lines to a file named `Makefile`, and invoke make as `make` in the same directory as this `Makefile`
2. or put these lines to a file with a name you like, such as `start.mk`, but invoke make as `make -f start.mk` in the same directory as this `start.mk`.

NOTE: every rules in the makefile is indented by a TAB, not some spaces. In this case, before every `$(CC) ..` lines should have and only have a TAB.

---

The "No rule to make target" error means you ask `make` to update a target according to the rules given by a Makefile, but the rule needed to update that target does not exist. This usually means you given a wrong target name in the command line.

For example, if you are using the above Makefile, but invoke `make` by this command: `make output`, because there is not rule that says how to update or generate `output`, `make` will give you that no-rule error.

Comment: make:Nothing to be done for 'start.mk', is coming. What it means?

Comment: @lokesharo Put them in a file named `Makefile`, then try to run `make all`.

Comment: @lokesharo Where this `start.mk` come from? What is the name of your makefile? What is the exactly command (including all its options) that you used to invoke `make`?

Comment: @lokesharo You need `-f start.mk`. You get the error message because you are missing the `-f`, so `make` thinks that `start.mk` is a target.